# What is the Stata 11 do-file editor shortcut for selecting a command line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, stata

A task I use multiple times a minute is to select command lines from my do-files and execute them.

The shortcut for this function in previous versions of Stata was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow. I used to use Stata 10 and now that I've upgraded to Stata 11, the keystroke sequence described in the previous sentence does nothing. I'm limited to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrows, which is painstakingly slow.

Comment: Go to the start of the line (with **Home** key) and then **shift + up/down**. That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the start of the line (with the <kbd>Home</kbd> key) and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Credit:
The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921170/what-is-the-stata-11-do-file-editor-shortcut-for-selecting-a-command-line#comment47970526_29921170) by [Roberto Ferrer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077064/roberto-ferrer)

Answer (score 0):

I automate the selecting of line and exectuting the command with the following  autohotkey script.:

```
^+Enter::Send {Control down}l{Control up}{pause}^d{down}{Home}

Return
```

Above is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it could be any keyboard combination. I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ö</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ä</kbd> since I use a scandinavian keyboard.

Same code as above but assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ö</kbd>:

```
^ö::Send {Control down}l{Control up}{pause}^d{down}{Home}

Return
```

If you prefer having the cursor at the end of the next line after executing, replace {Home} with {End}